# OAuth "invalid_scopes" error when requesting "click.sign" scope in DocuSign integration

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm working on integrating DocuSign into my application and I'm encountering an issue when trying to request the "click.sign" scope as part of the OAuth authentication process. Here are the details:

I receive an "invalid_scopes" error when attempting to authenticate when I include the "click.sign" scope in the OAuth request URL like this:

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation%20click.manage%20click.send%20click.sign&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/docusignCallback`

**It works without the click.sign in the above url**, but it seems that I will need this scope in order to be able to use **getAgreementDocument** method as per the [Click API documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/getagreementdocument/). (I am doing this as I need to be able to download the documents of the clickwrap agreement.

Is there a specific configuration or requirement for the "click.sign" scope in DocuSign that I might be missing?

Is there a known issue or limitation related to this scope?

Are there any rate limits or usage restrictions associated with this scope?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this "invalid_scopes" error and successfully request the "click.sign" scope in my DocuSign integration.

- My DocuSign integration has the necessary permissions for other scopes like "signature," "impersonation," "click.manage," and "click.send," and they work fine.
- I have verified that the scopes are spelled correctly and that the user consent process is functioning correctly. It works when I skip the click.sign from the scopes
- I'm using the correct OAuth redirect URI.
- I have reviewed my DocuSign integration settings, but I couldn't find any specific configuration for the "click.sign" scope.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such scope, the Click API scopes are only **click.manage** and **click.send**. Signing the agreement does not require any permission as it's done on the web browser without authentication or making API calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not just about signing the agreement. I want to be able to fetch the agreement document using getAgreementDocument method (as I have referred to in my question). There, they have mentioned click.sign as required authentication scope.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/getagreementdocument/

Comment: I think this page is wrong, sorry about that, it should be click.manage. I'll get this fixed ASAP